# TsLint: function invocation disallowed

Tags: typescript, tslint

I have some TypeScript code like this in my Visual Studio project

```
if (_.isNull(user)) {
  //Do stuff
}
```

And on save, TSLint gives me

```
Message TsLint: function invocation disallowed: _.isNull    BaseCtrl.ts    127
```

I **do** have the TypeScript definitions for Underscore.js in my project.

What does this message mean & how do I either fix my code to make TSLint happy or turn off this message in my `tslint.json` project settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with using isNull which appears to be on the function ban list.

https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/banRule.ts

The default ban list that comes with Web Essentials includes three ban rules:

```
"ban": [true,
       ["_", "extend"],
       ["_", "isNull"],
       ["_", "isDefined"]
 ],
```

Comment: that's it!  Thanks.  Any idea why they want to discourage these particular rules from being used?

Comment: It appears to be an example implementation more than a rule they are trying to enforce, it was added in [commit](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/commit/bc5cce7f13422d2f7c6bc26ce67df908277ddd9c) in response to [issue](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/56)

Comment: So, I should be safe to remove these rules from my project-level `tslint.json` file, correct?

Comment: Yes, the linting rules are configurable for a reason <3

Comment: <3 (on no, I have to write more characters, ok this should do it now)